# Como criar um banco de dados com ibm cloud storage e ibm cloud sql query

Tags: banco-de-dados, cloud, ibm

Boa noite,

Eu estou com problema para criar um banco de dados usando essas duas ferramentas da IBM, eu já criei o banco de dados no sql server e converti para CSV, após isso eu fiz o upload no storage, mas sempre que tento usar o comando de `INSERT`, pelo **IBM Cloud SQL Query**, ele apresenta o erro

> Error during job submission. SQL syntax validation failed. Syntax
>   error at line 1:0 mismatched input 'INSERT' expecting {'(', 'SELECT',
>   'WITH', 'VALUES'}.

Mesmo a *query* estando correta.

Alguém sabe como resolver isso?

Obrigado.